# How to scale/resize a box in plain TeX?

Tags: scaling, plain-tex

How can I resize (anamorphically) the contents of a box in plain TeX, that is, give it new width, height and depth?

```
\setbox0=\hbox{Hello!}
\copy0 % output at orig. size

%
% code which resizes box 0
% ... 
%

\box0  % output with altered dimensions
\bye
```

Comment: plain tex has no commands for scaling, You can use the latex interface with plain tex via `miniltx`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Thanks. I know that the `graphics` package can be used in plain TeX by means of `miniltx`. But isn't `graphics` implemented in TeX under the hood? Or does it delegate scaling to the output driver via `\special`?

Comment: It uses driver specific `\special` or other whatsits such as `\pdfliteral`

Comment: @AlexG If you don't want to use `graphics` via `miniltx` (or `eplain`), you basically have to define your own interface for the output driver(s) you're using: why reinventing the wheel? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg, I haven't started yet reinventing the wheel. I just asked in case implementing this is straightforward.

Comment: @AlexG The implementation is different for `tex+dvips`, `pdftex/luatex` `xetex+xdvipdfmx`; `graphicx` supports other drivers as well.

Comment: @David, egreg: I've never used them, but what about `\magnification` and `\magstep`s?

Comment: @morbusg Doesn't that do the entire page?

Comment: @AlexG Scaling _etc._ is a two-part task: you have to work out what the 'apparent' size is so your TeX reference points are right, then tell the driver to actually do the scaling of the boxed material. I did a re-implmentation for `expl3`, with lots of notes in the sources but using our FPU, so not directly applicable to plain.

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks, I am already using the `expl3` implementation `\box_resize:Nnn` in one of my packages. I simply wasn't aware of the fact that it is implemented in a driver-specific way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to get a hand on the problem, here's what one has to do with `pdftex`.

You can change the “current matrix” that tells `pdftex` how to resize the material it's going to print. Just save the current settings, change the matrix and restore.

```
\setbox0=\hbox{Abc}

X\copy0

\bigskip

X\pdfsave\pdfsetmatrix{0.87 -0.5 0.5 0.87}\rlap{\smash{\copy0}}\pdfrestore

\bigskip

X\box0

\bye
```

[image]

Do you see the problem? Between `\pdfsave` and `\pdfrestore` there should be no horizontal movement, so you need to compute the apparent dimension of the text you're transforming. Some trigonometry is needed in case of rotations, while scaling in either direction is easier. You'd use something like

```
\pdfsetmatrix{2 0 0 3}
```

for doubling in the x-direction and tripling in the y-direction and typeset an empty box with the apparent dimensions:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{Abc}

X\copy0 X

\bigskip

X\pdfsave\pdfsetmatrix{2 0 0 3}\rlap{\smash{\copy0}}\pdfrestore
{\setbox2=\hbox{}\wd2=2\wd0 \ht2=3\ht0 \dp2=3\dp0 \box2}X

\bigskip

X\box0 X

\bye
```

[image]

Note that proper space is reserved for the entire construction.

If you want to support also XeTeX, you'd have to use a completely different method, issuing suitable `\special` commands. Different `\special` commands would be needed for `latex+dvips`.

Comment: This is the kind of step-by-step instruction I hoped to get! Thank you very much! I will try to translate it into Postscript.

Comment: @AlexG `\rlap` is just one part; one should add also `\smash` in order to remove height and depth. I'll add it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this directly in plain TeX but is very easy to achieve in METAPOST, thus producing a picture that you can include in your document.

If you do not know METAPOST, you can start here

http://www.tug.org/metapost.html

and I especially like the [tutorial by André Heck](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~heck/Courses/mptut.pdf), which contains examples of what you want to do.

An example adapted from above mentioned tutorial:

```
beginfig(1);
picture pic; pic := image(
  draw btex $e^{\pi i}=-1$ etex;
  draw bbox currentpicture;
);

draw pic scaled 2.5;
draw pic scaled 1.5;
draw pic scaled 0.5;
endfig;
end;
```

results in

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With plain-XeTeX, one way could be to create the part which you'd want to be scaled, to be in a different file, and then `\XeTeXpdffile that_file_name.pdf scaled <amount>`. For example, the file `foo.tex` whose content is to be scaled:

```
\hoffset=-1in \voffset=-1in % remove 1 inch offsets
\hsize=20pc % divide \hsize by 1.5 (i.e., the amount to be scaled)
\def\strut{\vrule height.7\baselineskip depth.3\baselineskip width0pt }
\setbox0\hbox{\vbox{\strut
  Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
  lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. At vero eos et accusam et
  justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  \strut}}%
\pdfpagewidth=\wd0 \pdfpageheight=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0
\box0\bye
```

and the file using it `bar.tex`:

```
\hsize=30pc
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est.

\XeTeXpdffile foo.pdf scaled 1500 % 30pc divided by 1.5 (1500 here) is 20pc

Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\bye
```

results in:

[image]

(I think it's the `\parskip` at work between the included PDF and the last paragraph.)